# Using classes not designed for multiple sessions in servlet

Tags: java, session

I'm looking for a way to use a collection of Java classes in a servlet, which would provide some services to clients, but the classes were not designed with multiple sessions in mind, which seems to make that more difficult. To be specific, I want to load a language interpreter (ignoring security problems -- it will be accessible from localhost until I get security figured out), which has been written assuming there is just one user, so it has a lot of global state. Essentially I am looking for ways to ensure that each distinct client session has its own copy of the global state.

Is there a way to get the effect of sessions with an isolated copy of the global state by (let's say) working with the classloader? or some kind of container class? Maybe the servlet engine provides such a service? (I am working with Jetty, but I could switch to another servlet container if it provided such a service.)

Any light you can shed on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Containers don't give you this facility. Perhaps you can write some code to use a different classloader per user, but this is not a trivial task and IMMO you can do a better use of your time refactoring this code and removing the global state. Solve the problem instead of looking for difficult and complex workarounds.

Comment: If you have any advice about how to make it work with a per-user classloader, I'd like to hear about it. Of course, it would be best to refactor the code, but that's a big job; it is something like 50 kloc in about 300 classes. I think it's reasonable to look for a workaround under the circumstances.